# Preview app not working properly in macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, preview, mojave

After upgrading macOS to Mojave, Preview app is not functioning the same. 
I am no longer able to delete, drag & drop or select several files and open in the same window.

Is there a fix for this or do I need to go back to Sierra?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). In the meantime, I haven't noticed any problems with Preview app in macOS Mojave (at least not with using drag & drop or opening several files in the same window). In terms of no longer being able to delete, can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do with the Delete option?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure in Preview's preferences, that either **Open all files in one window** or **Open groups of files in the same window** is selected. If that looks OK and you're still experiencing the issue:

1. Quit Preview
2. Move ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist to the Trash
3. Re-launch Preview
4. Re-check preferences & ensure **Open all files in one window** or **Open groups of files in the same window** is selected
5. Attempt to reproduce your original issue

Comment: Well I tried that, but no change in response. I have looked for duplicate files and there were none. Do you have any other approaches to this ? I appreciate your input

Comment: I'm only able to replicate your issue by deliberately setting "Open each file in its own window" in Preview's preferences, even after creating a new test account on my Mac running 10.14.3. Can you try logging in as another user (use the Guest account or create and use a temporary account if needed) to see if the issue persists? Also, have you upgraded to the latest version of Mojave (10.14.3)?

Comment: I will try that and let you know how it goes. Yes I recently updated to 1.4.3 . I have also used the quick action drop down to build a pdf of selected files. It will open in one window, but it won't allow any deletions. Its grayed out. Bizarre....

Comment: I have a raw guest desk top that I logged into. I was able to do normal functions on that side. Now I am wondering what could be causing the issue on the normal login. Thanks for your input

Comment: Reboot. At the login window, enter the credentials for your primar login, but hold down the shift key while clicking on the "Log In" button. Release shift when you se the Dock appear. This will temporarily disable any login items from launching (like a Safe Mode but just for your account). Re-test. If resolved, go through your Login Items (System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items) and start playing whack-a-mole with them until you discover what's causing the issue.

Comment: Tried  the above and found no difference. Full safe boot up & account directions listed. Looking through my login on start up I don't actually show anything. I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: No worries — you've piqued my interest! Could be a launchd user process then, as these aren't technically login items (thus not disabled by holding down shift while logging in) and would only run in your primary login account. Take any .plist file you find in ~/Library/LaunchAgents and drag them to a new empty folder on your desktop and then reboot & re-test.

Comment: I can copy them ,but no provisions to trash & or move them? Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: well for some reason I can select random .png files and they all come up in one window with scroll & thumbnails. The mystery continues. Thnx again for all the help

Comment: wanted to update progress on this preview question. I pulled a copy of Sierra preview into a folder on the Mojave desktop. closed version 10 app reopened using version 9. Works fine so far. to over come the dual issue I pulled into the dock and set it to open at login. to be honest I did not think it would work. Thnx again

Answer (score 1):

I would make a brand new user account on this Mac and be sure it's reproducible. I would hate for you to have user permissions corruption and have this be fixed with a new user.

Also - be sure to try a couple PDF you get from printing a web page to a PDF or other "clean" PDF that come from pages or word and print to PDF as opposed to export to PDF.

Sometimes a class of older or crafted / complicated PDF can cause issues that take a couple months for Apple to fix. I have a couple Mojave PDF related bugs that still aren't fixed since they are rare/obsucure/took a while to convince Apple they were legit.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar issue on Mojave by

1. making sure the app was in my dock - if it's to the right of the divider line, move it to the left.
2. I quit the app,
3. then I held down the `Shift` key then clicked the Preview icon in the dock.

This may or may not fix your issue but it's worth trying.

Holding `Shift` while opening will start up the app without trying to ppen any of the windows it had open before.